# Warning: 'onCreateView' always returns non-null type

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Today I found this warning in all my fragments:

> Warning:(45, 12) 'onCreateView' always returns non-null type

onCreateView:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    ...
}
```

The question is, what has changed and why?

Android Studio version - 4.1.1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

this is `Kotlin` warning, probably new lint check for helping you producing better quality code

your method returns declared `View?`, but as we know in most cases this method shouldn't return `null` `View`, so this `?` (null safety) is redundant. just remove `?`, declare your method returns just `View` (not null by default in Kotlin)

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View { // in here no "?"
    ...
}
```

btw. [DOC](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) is saying that this method may return `null` and `Fragment` behaves then just like some objects/data holder, without UI, just for proper retaining instance across `Activity`s lifecycle. but in that case dev won't be overriding `onCreateView` at all